# How to fully translate c# lambda function to python?

Tags: python, selenium, lambda, selenium-webdriver

I new into lambda, and I wonder if someone could give me tips how C# return statement can be translate into python, and it is possible.

```
WebDrivrWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var imagesLink = wait.Until(d => 
                               {
                                  var elements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("kl"));
                                  if (elements.Count > 0)
                                  return elements[0];
                                  return null;
                               });
imagesLink.Click();
```

The simple selenium explicit waits doesn't work for my and almost all the time I getting timeout error, while running test on FB.
So far I've figured out the wait assignment function, but don't have an idea how to create the variable and if statement with return value within lambda. Are there any good tuts about?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "The simple selenium explicit waits doesn't work" - what code did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *possible* (but ugly, confusing and unnecessary), without calling `find_elements` twice, using nested lambdas:

```
f = lambda: (lambda x: x[0] if len(x) > 0 else "Argh" )([1,2,3])
f()  # returns 1

f = lambda: (lambda x: x[0] if len(x) > 0 else "Argh" )([])
f()  # returns "Argh"
```

So for your selenium example you *could* do something like:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(lambda d: (lambda x: x[0] if len(x) > 0 else None)(d.find_elements_by_class_name("k1")))
```

However, since you are just trying to return the first element, you should be able to do this much more simply using the selenium 2 [expected conditions API](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html):

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "k1"))
```

Nested lambdas are a fun trick, but I strongly recommend you do not use them in real code!

Answer (score 1):

Python lambda functions are quite limited and can only contain a single expression. While you *could,* theoretically, write the lambda in your C# example as a single expression, because you can't do an assignment, you'd have to call `driver.FindElements` twice, which is verbose and inefficient. Instead, use a named function.